# How to implement Spring Boot Security OAuth2 with Keyclaok and Swagger

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, swagger-ui

I want to be able to log in via Swagger UI using Keycloak and Spring Boot Security. So far, i can log in with bearer generated token via postman, but how to configure user credentials login?

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {"/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "v3/api-docs",
            "/api/public/**", "/api/public/authenticate", "/actuator/*", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**"};

    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(o2 -> o2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)));
        http.sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Converterer:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();

    @Value("${jwt.auth.converter.principle_attribute}")
    private String principleAttribute;
    @Value("${jwt.auth.converter.resource-id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream.concat(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(), extractResourceRoles(jwt).stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, getPrincipleClaimName(jwt));
    }

    private String getPrincipleClaimName(Jwt jwt) {
        String claimName = JwtClaimNames.SUB;
        if (principleAttribute != null) {
            claimName = principleAttribute;
        }
        return jwt.getClaim(claimName);
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(Jwt jwt) {
        Map<String, Object> resourceAccess;
        Map<String, Object> resource;
        Collection<String> resourceRoles;
        if (jwt.getClaim("resource_access") == null) {
            return Set.of();
        }
        resourceAccess = jwt.getClaim("resource_access");

        if (resourceAccess.get(resourceId) == null) {
            return Set.of();
        }
        resource = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get(resourceId);

        resourceRoles = (Collection<String>) resource.get("roles");
        return resourceRoles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Swagger config:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    private static final String OAUTH_SCHEME_BEARER = "bearerAuth";

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customizeOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                        .addList(OAUTH_SCHEME_BEARER))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(OAUTH_SCHEME_BEARER, new SecurityScheme()
                                .name(OAUTH_SCHEME_BEARER)
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                .scheme("bearer")
                                .bearerFormat("JWT")));
    }

}
```

Any suggestions or tutorial links, would be welcoming, I tried what I could find, but with no luck.

Comment: with swagger you also can do it with jwt token as in postman.

Comment: @AndreiLisa yes, that is exactly what i'm currently doing, is there a way to directly login in swagger ui with keycloak credentials?

Comment: no, you didn't get it right, swagger in an api interface like postman to access values from there you should be login also how in postman by token.

Comment: okay @AndreiLisa , that is exactly what I'm trying to do, can you show some examples please?

Comment: i wrote an answer, could you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to re-write my swagger config, and it looks like this:

```
private static final String OAUTH_SCHEME = "auth";

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
String authURL;

@Bean
public OpenAPI customizeOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement()
                    .addList(OAUTH_SCHEME))
            .components(new Components()
                    .addSecuritySchemes(OAUTH_SCHEME, createOAuthScheme()))
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(OAUTH_SCHEME));
}

private SecurityScheme createOAuthScheme() {
    return new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2).flows(createOAuthFlows());
}

private OAuthFlows createOAuthFlows() {
    final var oauthFlow = new OAuthFlow()
            .authorizationUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/auth")
            .refreshUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/token")
            .tokenUrl(authURL + "/protocol/openid-connect" + "/token")
            .scopes(new Scopes());
    return new OAuthFlows().authorizationCode(oauthFlow);
}
```

I also had to add some configurations in my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081

keycloak:
  username: test-client
  password: *****
  realm: test-realm
  uri: http://localhost:8080
  auth-server-url: ${keycloak.uri}/realms/${keycloak.realm}/protocol/openid-connect

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      clientId: ${keycloak.username}
      clientSecret: ${keycloak.password}

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${keycloak.uri}/realms/${keycloak.realm}
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${keycloak.uri}/realms/${keycloak.realm}

jwt:
  auth:
    converter:
      resource-id: ${keycloak.username}
      principle_attribute: preferred_username
```

It works now, by redirecting to keycloak logging page, i'm also pre-filling client id and secret in properties to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in comments, i think that you cannot access endpoints of application by swagger and also based on the code that you provided i can say that you should change your swagger config:

Something like this:

**OpenApi Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
  
  @Bean
  public OpenAPI myAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .components(new Components()
            .addSecuritySchemes("bearer-key",
                new SecurityScheme()
                    .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                    .scheme("bearer")
                    .bearerFormat("JWT")
            )
        )
        .info(getApiInfo())
        .addSecurityItem(
            new SecurityRequirement()
                .addList("bearer-jwt", Arrays.asList("read", "write"))
                .addList("bearer-key", Collections.emptyList())
        );
  }
  

  private Info getApiInfo() {
    return new Info()
        .title("Application Backend API")
        .description("APIS")
        .version("version")
        .contact(getContacts())
        .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org"));
  }

  private Contact getContacts() {
    return new Contact()
        .name("app name")
        .url("url")
        .email("mail");
  }
}
```

After it if you will open open api url(`...swagger-ui/index.html`) and click `Authorize` button after it insert your `JWT` token here like how you do in postman all will work great.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The Authorization Code Flow in OAuth 2.0 is a process in which a client(in your case **postman**)obtains an authorization code from an authorization server and then uses the code to acquire access tokens from the token server, after it with token(client) can access secured endpoints from resource-server(your application that run on `8081`). It mean that swagger-ui cannot be configured also to obtain token.

A good article about this topic [oauth-authorization-code-grant-type](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type)

Comment: No, you misunderstood me, your code didn't change anything, I don't want to paste a bearer, I want to log in with keyclaok credentials! Now I have to take it an extra step and go to postman to get token, to log in... my question is, how to configure it, so I can log in DIRECTLY in swagger UI with keyclaok credentials.

Comment: i am  sure on postman, to take jwt you pass credentials to an different `url` than `url` of the application, for example application `localhost:8080` and  Keycloak `localhost:8081`, am i right ?

Comment: yes, it's http://localhost:8080/realms/test-relm/protocol/openid-connect/token for keycloak, for api i'm using different port (8081)

Comment: in this case, you cant do it because it is 2 different application, i mean swagger is an API just for `8081`, what you try to to it is a bad ideea. I am going to update my answer with oAuth 2.0 `grand_type=authorization_code` flow, usually so are working many web application .

Comment: i just updated my answer, i think it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Have you got me ?

Comment: just added the changes I had to make in order for it to work as intended, thank you for your contribution.